# Setting the CSS of an html element with text entered by the user

Tags: javascript, html, css

My page has two textareas and a div. One textarea is for the user to enter html and the other is for entering css. When a button is clicked I will call a javascript function to display the css and html inside the div.

```js
function handleLaunch() {
  var div = document.getElementById('pane');
  var html = document.getElementById('h');

  var css = document.getElementById('c');

  div.innerHTML = html.value;
  // This line obviously doesn't work div.style = css.value;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <textarea id="c" placeholder="CSS code here..." rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
  <div id="pane">

  </div>
  <br>
  <textarea id="h" placeholder="Html code here..." rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
  <br>
  <button type="button" onclick="handleLaunch()">Launch</button>
```

Now, how to set the css to the text ?

EDIT: I should have mentioned that I want to be able to put something like 
.classExample{text-align:center} in the css textarea and have it apply.

Comment: Anyway `div.style.cssText = css.value` would let you type CSS in the input

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work

Comment: You sure **div.style.cssText = "background-color: red";** does not work?

Comment: Would it not make more sense to setup up a 3 column input with the ability to add multiple rows. So you would have ID, Class & CSS, Then you could add or remove rows as necessary so then you could target specific ID's or class names.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Could you give me a coded example?

Comment: Use an <iframe>, then this: `document.getElementById('pane').contentWindow.document.write("<style>" + css + "</style>" + html);`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, @adeneo answer works, this snippet shows it. Enter `color: red;` for example as CSS, and any text as HTML...

```js
function handleLaunch() {
  var div = document.getElementById('pane');
  var html = document.getElementById('h');

  var css = document.getElementById('c');

  div.innerHTML = html.value;
  div.style.cssText = css.value;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <textarea id="c" placeholder="CSS code here..." rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
  <div id="pane">

  </div>
  <br>
  <textarea id="h" placeholder="Html code here..." rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
  <br>
  <button type="button" onclick="handleLaunch()">Launch</button>
```

Comment: This only sets the style for the entire div. I should have clarified that I want to be able to use classes and id's in the css textarea. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are defining css properties along with selectors, for example you css text is like

```
div{
    background:red;
}
.someClass{
    font-size:12px;
}
```

and your html looks like

```
<div>DIV content</div>
<span class="someClass"> Content in someClass</span>
```

You can add the html as `div.innerHTML = html.value;`

But for adding the css to your page you will have to do the following

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';
style.innerHTML = document.getElementById('c').value;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style)
```